# Python: map a list of tuples onto the keys of a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, mapping

Given the following list of tuples:

```
l=[((459301.5857207412, 443923.4365563169),
   (458772.4179957388, 446370.8372844439))]
```

And the following dictionary:

```
mydict={0: (459301.5857207412, 443923.4365563169),
        25: (458772.4179957388, 446370.8372844439)}
```

How could I create a new list where the tuple contains the key in `mydict` associated with the values of the tuple itself?

The result would be, given the two examples above:

```
mapped=[(0,25)]
```

Comment: What if in the dictionary several keys have the same value?

Comment: This is not possible, as the numbers in the brackets uniquely identify points in the space. So these values have a geographical meaning, and I have paid much attention to not placing two points in the same location.

Comment: `l` is a list with 1 element, containing a tuple of tuples. expected?

Comment: The expected result would be `mapped=[(0,25)]`, which in this *simple* case is a list with 1 tuple. I did not add other values as the digits would have made the question rather unreadable.

Comment: Is the order important? If `l` were reversed, would `[(0,25)]` still be correct output?

Comment: What do you mean by reversed? `l` is a list containing a tuple of tuples. Each one of the latter is an indivisible and unalterable combination of two X, Y coordinates. The tuple that contains these two smaller tuples is an edge in a graph. If you reverse it, you get 25->0 instead of 0->25. In my specific case this is not a problem, as this link works *both ways*. In other cases you might not want to mess up with these directions.

Comment: @CF84 Sorry, I forgot the nesting, I meant what if `l[0]` were reversed. I.e., whether `[(0,25)]` would still be correct after doing `l[0] = l[0][::-1]` or whether output should then be `[(25,0)]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If

```
l=[((459301.5857207412, 443923.4365563169),
   (458772.4179957388, 446370.8372844439))]

mydict={0: (459301.5857207412, 443923.4365563169),
        25: (458772.4179957388, 446370.8372844439)}
```

I suppose I could generalize your simple case with this oneliner:

```
[tuple(k for k,v in mydict.items() if v in sl) for sl in l]
```

result:

```
[(0, 25)]
```

Note: for better performance, it would be better to pre-process `l` to create sets inside like this so lookup with `in` is faster (tuples are immutable/hashable, so let's take advantage of it):

```
l = [set(x) for x in l]
```

Answer (score 3):

In most simple case it can be achieved using a regular `for in` loop:

```
mapped = [()]
for k in mydict:
    if mydict[k] in l:
        mapped[0] += (k, )

print(mapped)
```

The output:

```
[(0, 25)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a reverse dictionary. Fast and (unlike the other solutions) keeps the order.

```
>>> reverse = {v: k for k, v in mydict.items()}
>>> [tuple(map(reverse.get, sub)) for sub in l]
[(0, 25)]
```

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
l = [((459301.5857207412, 443923.4365563169),(458772.4179957388, 446370.8372844439))]
d = {0: (459301.5857207412, 443923.4365563169),
     25: (458772.4179957388, 446370.8372844439)}


mapped = []
for t in l:
    m = []
    for k,v in d.items():
        if v in l[0]:
            m.append(k)
    mapped.append(tuple(m))


>>>print(mapped)
>>>[(0, 25)]
```